# Archivos con información faltante al enviar por socket, cliente Python a servidor Nodejs utilizando Socket.io

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, nodejs, socket.io

Estoy trabajando con un servidor Nodejs y Socket.io en el cual necesito enviarle un archivo el archivo se lo envío desde un cliente python utilizando Python socketio[client], el archivo con el que he estado haciendo pruebas es un vídeo que tiene un peso de **43,784,501 bytes** un total de 41 megabytes mas o menos. Cual es el inconveniente? Pues que al enviar el archivo leo los bytes y los voy enviando en trozos de **4096 bytes** y mediante el modulo fs de Node voy haciendo append a esos bytes que me han llegado.
Al momento de terminar el envío del archivo, veo que el archivo tiene la misma cantidad de bytes que en el origen, pero por alguna razón el archivo muchas veces llega corrupto y otras veces no, corrupto en el sentido que aveces dice que no se conoce el formato del vídeo y otras veces hay cortes en el vídeo, como si faltara información. He intentado "dormir" el cliente con time.sleep() durante unos milisegundos luego de enviar cada trozo y de hecho si ha funcionado la mayoria de veces, el problema con esto es que no es muy optimo ya que la subida es extremadamente lenta al hacer esto. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como se podria solucionar esto? Dejare el código acá abajo.

Cliente python:

```
@cliente.on('descarga_archivo')
def envia_archivo(data):
    archi = directorio_actual+sep+data

    if os.path.isfile(archi):
        print(archi)
        # cont = 0
        with open(archi, "rb") as f:
            longitud_b = os.path.getsize(archi)
            longitud_env = 0 #cantidad de bytes enviados
            while True:
                #LEER BYTES
                byte = f.read(1024 * 4)
                longitud_env = longitud_env + len(byte)
                
                if not byte:
                    cliente.emit('remote:recibe_archivo',
                                {'bytes': '', 'total_bytes': longitud_b,
                                'longitud_env' : longitud_env, 'nombre' : data, 
                                'terminado': True}, callback=test_callback)
                     break
                else:
                    cliente.emit('remote:recibe_archivo',{'bytes': byte, 
                                                        'total_bytes': longitud_b,
                                                        'longitud_env' : longitud_env, 
                                                        'nombre' : data, 
                                                        'terminado': False}, callback=test_callback)
                        
                       
                f.flush()
    else:
        print("Archivo no existe")
```

Servidor Nodejs

```
socket.on('remote:recibe_archivo', (data, callback) => {

    if(data['terminado'] == false){
        
        fs.appendFile(data['nombre'], data['bytes'], (err, fd) => {
            
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        let porcentaje_reciv = Math.round( (data['longitud_env']/data['total_bytes'])*100);
        cliente_web.emit('estado_descarga', {'porcentaje': porcentaje_reciv, 'terminado': false});
        
    }else{
        cliente_web.emit('estado_descarga', {'porcentaje': 100, 'terminado': true});
    }

    callback(0);
})
```

Comment: Una forma de evitar la posible corrupción de datos es implementar un sistema de verificación de la data enviada y recibida, mediante algún *checksum* u otro tipo de verificación. No veo que tengas implementado nada parecido. Saludos

Comment: Tiene pinta de problema de codificación. Te sugeriría que codificaras en *base64* los `byte` que envías desde el cliente, y en el servidor hicieras lo opuesto.